# My axios instance does not work and I do not know why

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have created a seperate axios.js file for an axios instance to make requests to an API I have running live. When I use the axios instance in my login route I get a
POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/login 404 (Not Found) error, even though the url defined in my axios instance is not my localhost it is the url of the API. Now, when I use axios in my login route and enter the whole API url instead of using the instance, the POST request goes to the correct url and I get proper response. I do not understand this. Everything on the API is fine and has been tested many times AND I have used an axios instance like this before.

here is the instance I have set up(baseUrl is correct in my code):

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseUrl: REMOVED,
  headers: {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      ? 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      : null,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

here is the login function that uses my axios instance and does not work:

```
export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  axiosInstance
    .post('/login', { email: email, password: password })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    });
};
```

here is the login function that works perfectly:

```
export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post('fullurlnotshown/login', { email: email, password: password })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    });
};
```

EDIT: SOLVED THE PROBLEM... 'baseUrl:' in the instance should be 'baseURL:'

Comment: When you make the request with axios (not your instance) are you also including the headers that you have set on your axios instance?

Comment: @rdrw I've tried not including them AND including and still get same error. For some reason when I use the instance it sends the axios request to localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be referencing the wrong property of `baseUrl`. The [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) has the property as `baseURL` (URL instead of Url).

Axios is probably silently ignoring your incorrect property key and falling back to localhost.